# 500 (internal server error) using Ajax in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a like and dislike a button and store the info through ajax in Laravel 5.2. I am using **wamp** as my localhost.
**At first, I saw sometimes the like and dislike was counted, and sometimes they weren't.**
So, I tried to see it in the console through console.log(), and found 500(internal Server Error) **in some of my clicks.**
I also made sure the csrf token is provided properly.

I don't know how to deal with an error which sometimes come and sometimes doesn't.

this is my **likeajax.js** :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
var postId=0;

    $('.option1').on('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $('event').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: urlLike,
                data: {postId: postId, _token: token},
            })



    });

    $('.optionx').on('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $('event').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlDislike,
            data: {postId: postId, _token: token},
        })

    });
```

this is my **LikeController**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Depress;
use App\Http\Requests;

class LikeController extends Controller
{
    public function postLike(Request $request)
    {
        $post_id = $request['postId'];
        $post = Depress::find($post_id);
        $post->like = $post->like+1;
        $post->save();
        return null;
    }

    public function postDislike(Request $request)
    {
        $post_id = $request['postId'];
        $post = Depress::find($post_id);
        $post->dislike = $post->dislike+1;
        $post->save();
        return null;
    }
}
```

this is in my like **layout.blade.php**,

```
<script>
    var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
    var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
    var urlDislike = '{{ route('dislike') }}';
</script>
```

UPDATE:
though when I go to the page : http://localhost:8000/dislike ,

it shows

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you get in the 500 response?

Comment: Open the network tab of your browser inspector, select the ajax call and look at the response it returned. In this response you will find the error and probably find the solution.

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/dislike?_token=MNPgbBJZJ5rRuo75jwTPXrueLiUzroIAM2UGhWPc 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:4ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ likeajax.js:33dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: That is the return of your console. We need the response from you ajax call in order to see what is wrong. Are you using Chrome? Press F+12, click network, click ajax call, click repsonse and update your question with it.

Comment: Also, are you sure it always gets the correct post id?

Comment: these are the response headers i could get,
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 28 Jun 2016 08:28:42 GMT
Host:localhost:8000
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjZCWmhIRE1kbFwvSHBIb3hxVWpFdFVnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlwvSHhsNGZ4cnhoRHVIWlYycERzOFFsT05Za2VHc0U0UFJRQXhwaDJZOGo1MHh2UlZPN3RhR1Z6TFZEVnhBSjNLTkdCeEpIK3dNdFMwb0t6SEVrUVwvNnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjQzYWE3M2NmOGQ4YjBiODkzZTEzZjY3YTY0MzZjZDhmZTgxNDAwZmIyNTYxOGYxYTFiMDY3NDY1MmJmMzg3ZmMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 28-Jun-2016 10:28:42 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.12

Comment: Yeah, the post id is correct, I have checked that

Comment: We do not need the headers but the response. Click on "Response" two tabs next to "Headers".

Comment: Yeah, I have posted the response, scroll down to see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `$post_id` is `NULL`.

Try `$request->input('postId')` instead of `$request['postId']`.

Also you should consider using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: still the problem persists

Comment: Also, if the $post_id is NULL, how is this working sometimes?

Comment: Okay, change `method: 'GET'` in your javascript to `method: 'POST'`. Don't forget to change your route to POST.

Comment: Check if your `postId` really being send. You can check this in the "Header" tab of your ajax call. Scroll down until you see "Form Data". Do you see the `postId` in there? Also if a `Depress` model with that `postId` exists in your database?

Comment: when I go to the page : http://localhost:8000/dislike ,

it shows

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218                     Maybe, this can help

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good thing to orientate more on the laravel framework. Read articles, watch tutorials and such. Learn about the life cycle of this framework and know what these kind of errors mean.